# Should we "super()" in base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, method-resolution-order

In Python 3 I use super from inherited classes as follows:

```
class Orange(Fruit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

In the code snippet above `Orange` class inherits from `Fruit` class. Take a look at the parent class

```
class Fruit():
    def __init__(self):
        pass       # call super().__init__() here?
```

Do we need to call super from the parent/base class for the MRO to work effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Python there's no point in calling `__init__` on `super` for base classes and the MRO will still be properly initialised

Comment: Unless you use multiple inheritance.